Transformation of variables for Markov chain transition density
Consider a Markov chain with an uncountable state space that starts in the state $x_0$. The one-step transition density of the Markov chain is given by
$$
\tag{1}
p(x_0,x)=\mathbf 1_{\{x\leq x_0-\theta_2\ \cup\ x\geq x_0+\theta_1\}}\frac{1}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)+\delta(x-x_0)\left(\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-\mu+\theta_1}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{x_0-\mu-\theta_2}{\sigma}\right)\right),
$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the standard normal pdf and cdf, respectively. The function $p(x_0,x)$ is a density function in $x$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x_0,x)\,\mathrm dx=1$. The $n$-step transition density is given by
$$
p^{(n)}(x_0,x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p^{(m)}(x_0,z)p^{(n-m)}(z,x)\,\mathrm dz.
$$
And assuming a stationary distribution exists, the stationary distribution is given by
$$
\pi(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p^{(n)}(x_0,x),
$$
which is independent of the initial state $x_0$.
Now let $X$ describe the random variable given by the one-step transition density $(1)$ and suppose we perform the change of variables $Z=(X-\mu)/\sigma$ so that the one-step transition density of $Z$ is given by
$$
p(z_0,z)=\mathbf 1_{\{z\leq z_0-\theta_2/\sigma\ \cup\ z\geq z_0+\theta_1/\sigma\}}\phi\left(z\right)+\delta(z-z_0)\left(\Phi\left(z_0+\theta_1/\sigma\right)-\Phi\left(z_0-\theta_2/\sigma\right)\right),
$$
where $z_0=(x_0-\mu)/\sigma$. The stationary distribution of this transformed process is
$$
\xi(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p^{(n)}(z_0,z),
$$
which is independent of $z_0$.
Assuming I haven't made any mistakes my two questions are:
(1) Is it true that the stationary distribution $\xi(z)$ does not have $\mu$ as a parameter? I believe the answer is yes because even though $z_0$ contains $\mu$ the stationary distribution is independent of $z_0$ (and thus not functionally dependent on $\mu$).
(2) Is $\pi(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\xi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$? In other words, does a linear transformation of the one-step transition density $(1)$ mean the stationary distributions $\pi(x)$ and $\xi(z)$ are related through the same linear transformation?
